# Getting all documents from one collection in cloud Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm starting to learn Android and try to solve this problem for hours. Maybe someone will explain to me how to get all documents from collection -> document from Firestore?

```
package com.aak.daywork.Activities.ui.home;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.aak.daywork.Adapters.PostAdapter;
import com.aak.daywork.Models.Post;
import com.aak.daywork.R;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;
    RecyclerView postRecyclerView;
    PostAdapter postAdapter;
    FirebaseFirestore firestore;
    DocumentReference documentReference;

    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseUser currentUser;

    List<Post> postList;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        postRecyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.postRv);
        postRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        String id = currentUser.getUid();

        documentReference = firestore.collection("Post").document(id);
         //Я пытался это
       // Я получаю только через id

        return root;
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        documentReference.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                postList = new ArrayList<>();
                Post post = documentSnapshot.toObject(Post.class);
                postList.add(post);
                postAdapter = new PostAdapter(getActivity(), postList);
                postRecyclerView.setAdapter(postAdapter);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Often, it is very useful to read the official documentation, in which everything is well-written.

```
firestore.collection("Post")
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
```

This code was advised to me. I did not understand how to embed it in my code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUFzf.png)

Comment: Arman Abdulun what is the problem

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot. Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: I corrected my question and added a screenshot

Answer (score 2):

> Use **addSnapshotListener()** method to get all the documents in one collection

```
firestore.collection("Post")
         .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                    if (documentSnapshot != null && !documentSnapshot.getDocuments().isEmpty()) {
                        
                        List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = documentSnapshot.getDocuments();
                        for (DocumentSnapshot value : documents) {
                            
                            Map<String, Object> mapInfo = value.getData();
                            if (mapInfo != null) {

                                String path = value.getReference().getPath();
                                switch (path) {

                                    case "Post" + "/" + "2E3eQpxe....9Y12":
                                        JSONObject info1 = new JSONObject(mapInfo);
                                        info1.optString("city", "");
                                        info1.optString("date", "");
                                        break;

                                    case "Post" + "/" + "D7RP0KLv....fwCh2":
                                        JSONObject info2 = new JSONObject(mapInfo);
                                        info2.optString("city", "");
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

**CODE:**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;
    private RecyclerView postRecyclerView;
    private PostAdapter postAdapter;
    private FirebaseFirestore firestore;
    private DocumentReference documentReference;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseUser currentUser;

    private List<Post> postList;
    private String userId;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();

        homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        postRecyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.postRv);
        postRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        userId = currentUser.getUid();
    
        firestore.collection("Post")
                .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                        if (documentSnapshot != null && !documentSnapshot.getDocuments().isEmpty()) {
                            postList = new ArrayList<>();
                            List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = documentSnapshot.getDocuments();
                            for (DocumentSnapshot value : documents) {
                                Post post = value.toObject(Post.class);
                                postList.add(post);
                            }
                            postAdapter = new PostAdapter(getActivity(), postList);
                            postRecyclerView.setAdapter(postAdapter);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

and let me know if this not works.

Comment: take care that using  `addSnapshotListener() ` will keep listening to values , whenever a value changes it will trigger your  `onEvent ` callback ,  `.addOnCompleteListener ` will be a one time fetch operation

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I can’t understand how I can add this to my code, you can explain how to add the code with official documentation to my code

Comment: @ArmanAbdullin check out this updated snippet and let me know if you have still doubt.

Comment: Arindam Karmakar  Thank you very much, your code works, you helped me a lot. Can I contact you later? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help but you can help with something else. Tama is the same thing I used your code to get Post
but how to get the value here. Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60374474/how-to-get-data-from-firebase-firestore

Comment: Welcome @ArmanAbdullin, you can contact me later, and please accept my answer by clicking on the check option below the upvote option, thanks!