# How to get data from Firebase Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In this code I added "Comment" in firestore this is not problem.

```
btnAddComment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btnAddComment.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                DocumentReference comment = firestore.collection("Comment").document(postKey);
                String comment_content = editTextComment.getText().toString();
                String uid = currentUser.getUid();
                String uname = currentUser.getDisplayName();
                String uimg = currentUser.getPhotoUrl().toString();
                Comment comm = new Comment(comment_content, uid, uimg, uname);

                comment.set(comm).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        showMessage("Добавлено");
                        editTextComment.setText("");
                        btnAddComment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        showMessage("Не добавлено: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

And here's how to stitch it:

```
private void iniRvComment() {
        RwComment.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        DocumentReference docRef = firestore.collection("Comment").document(postKey);
        docRef.collection("Comment").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                if (documentSnapshot != null && !documentSnapshot.getDocuments().isEmpty()) {
                    listComment = new ArrayList<>();
                    List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = documentSnapshot.getDocuments();
                    for (DocumentSnapshot value : documents) {

                        Comment comment = value.toObject(Comment.class);
                        listComment.add(comment);
                    }
                    commentAdapter = new CommentAdapter(getApplicationContext(), listComment);
                    RwComment.setAdapter(commentAdapter);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I want to display the "Comment" field with firestore using "postKey" as the key but I can understand how this code works, watched it all on the official Firebase website. I have a "Post" under each post the user leaves a comment, the problem is that something is not displayed.

Comment: Could you share the error it's giving?

Answer (score 0):

The above code won't work because of your database reference declaration. If you want to retrieve all the comments just provide collection referece.

```
firestore.collection("Comment").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
        if (documentSnapshot != null && !documentSnapshot.getDocuments().isEmpty()) {
            listComment = new ArrayList<>();
            List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = documentSnapshot.getDocuments();
            for (DocumentSnapshot value : documents) {

                Comment comment = value.toObject(Comment.class);
                listComment.add(comment);
            }
            commentAdapter = new CommentAdapter(getApplicationContext(), listComment);
            RwComment.setAdapter(commentAdapter);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see in your screenshot, you have a schema that looks like this:

```
Firestore-root
    |
    --- Comment (collection)
          |
          --- docId
               |
               --- content: "hfjnncjf"
```

If you want to get all `Comment` objects, you only need to use the following `CollectionReference`:

```
CollectionReference commentRef = firestore.collection("Comment");
commentRef.addSnapshotListener(/* ... */);
```

What is wrong in your code is the addition of `.collection("Comment")` call on your `commentRef` object. What you are doing, you are assuming that you have a subcollection within your `commentRef` document, which is wrong. You don't have such a subcollection there.

If you want to get a single comment, then you should use the following line of code:

```
DocumentReference commentRef = firestore.collection("Comment").document(postKey);
```

But without iterating, because you only get one document.

**Edit:**

To get the value of your `content` property and listen for changes in real-time, please use the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
DocumentReference commentRef = firestore.collection("Comment").document("ZQMqIrx19fftjO3ZeSzkuEw87MY2");
commentRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
        if (e != null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
            return;
        }

        if (snapshot != null && snapshot.exists()) {
            Log.d(TAG, snapshot.getString("content"));
        }
    }
});
```

The output in your logcat will be:

```
hfjnncjf
```

Comment: I have (Post) under each of these posts leave a (Сomment)
I use "String postKey" as a key. I need to get a "Comment" under each "Post"

Comment: Post(ZQMqIrx19fftjO3ZeSzkuEw87MY2)                                              
                       |                                                                                                                 
Comment(postKey(ZQMqIrx19fftjO3ZeSzkuEw87MY2))

Comment: Firestore-root
    |
    --- Collection("Comment")
          |
          --- document(postKey()
               |
               --- content: "hfjnncjf"

Comment: So have you tried to use only the reference from my answer? Does it work that way?

Comment: There is a “Post” under the post, users leave the “Comment” program works; everything is saved, but there is a problem, I can’t put out all these “Comment” under each “Post” written code I took from the official site I can’t understand why it doesn’t work

Comment: The question is, am I using the wrong code or using the wrong code, help explain what am I doing wrong?

Comment: collection(Comment) -> document(postKey) -> child(content)

Comment: how get "content" current "Comment"?

Comment: So in your picture, you want to get the value of content property which `hfjnncjf`, right? Do you need it in real-time or you want to use it only once.

Comment: Real-Time  Comment

Comment: So in your picture, you want to get the value of `content` property which `hfjnncjf`, right?

Comment: yes I need content: "hfjnncjf" of the current "Comment"

Comment: Okay, sorry, I'm not strong in English and apparently my question is dumb, right now I will reformulate my question I'll try to ask this question again. Thanks for the help

Comment: So did my edited answer work? Have you even tried it?

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException.java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Comment: Please edit your question with exact code that you are using and leave a message here.

Comment: you can look at the code again and help me. I think everything is correctly supplemented